# MoarFonts broken in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5.1

For the past 4 months, I've been using [Moarfonts](http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/), a Build Phase Run Script that allows you to use custom fonts in Interface Builder.

Today, when trying to build my app, the compiler thew a bunch of errors like this:

> error: Failed to install Brandon Grotesque Bold: The file “Brandon_bld.otf” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Not sure if these are related, but today, before building and failing, I:

- Upgraded to Xcode 5.1.1 from 5.1
- Opened up a copy of Xcode 4.6 to build and run an older project of mine
- Back in Xcode 5.1.1, ran the following commands in the terminal at Xcode's request:

  - sudo chmod a+w /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/.lilid
  - sudo chmod a+w /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/.lilid/.lilic

I've removed all the fonts from the Copy Bundle Resources Build Phase, and everything else looks sane.

Any ideas?

Comment: [You 're not alone](http://blog.zats.io)

Comment: And [here is the author's troubleshooting](http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/#troubleshooting) as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Running `/usr/local/bin/moarfonts reset` in a build phase once, then restarting Xcode again helped me. Afterwards you should remove the build phase again.

Comment: I get `error: SDKROOT environment variable is not set` in the terminal

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I forgot: You have to run this as a build phase. I'll update my answer.

Comment: actually, the 2nd symptom, 2nd solution on the developer website lists the solution, which is similar to yours, but you have to export SDKRoot first. http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/. I can't believe I missed that. I think I read Solution 1 but not 2. Doh!

Comment: Ah, I only saw them now from the comments on your question. If you run it as a build phase you don't need to set the SDKROOT, xcodebuild will take care of this. But the command line solution is cleaner I think.

Comment: Solution 2 on the developers site worked for me. pitaya.ch/moarfonts.